# How subtype can be added to a supertype list via Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to do something like this which compiles fine:

```
public interface Training {
    public void train();
}

public class JavaTraining implements Training{

    @Override
    public void train() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}

import java.util.*;

public class TestClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Training> trainingList = new ArrayList<Training>();
        trainingList.add(new JavaTraining());
        for(Training trainingItem : trainingList){
            trainingItem.train();
        }

    }

}
```

This compiles fine and runs also.

But when I try to change the main method like below it give a compile time error.

Why is that?

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Training> trainingList = new ArrayList<JavaTraining>();
    }

}
```

The compile time error is:

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to List"

I have even read one post [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/5-things-you-should-know-about-java-generics). But it does not clear my doubt.

The question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit) since I have not used anywhere

```
List<? extends Training>
```

But still it is accepting the objects of JavaTraining. How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is why you cannot do this:

```
List<JavaTraining> jt = new ArrayList<JavaTraining>(); // So far so good
List<Training> trainingList = jt; // This is what you did; let's pretend it compiles
trainingList.add(new CobolTraining()); // The compiler must allow this, because `CobolTraining` is a `Training`.
```

The problem with the above is that it lets you put a `CobolTraining` into `jt`, a list of `JavaTraining`.

Comment: According to Java generics inheritance does not work when try to put in objects of sub type into a super type collection.

Comment: @Sam That's precisely why the line in the middle is disallowed: had it been allowed, you'd easily bypass the restriction by doing what you did.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to how generics are designed. `ArrayList<JavaTraining>` does not extend `ArrayList<Training>`.

You should do

```
  List<? extends Training> trainingList = new ArrayList<JavaTraining>();
```

Check the use of **wildcards**.

Comment: why should I do it if it is working without it?